# Spring security whiltelist incoming service call

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-security

In Spring security you can whitelist the incoming IP using hasIpAddress. Is it possible to have a whitelist for the incoming domain/url/servicename?

I have two services in a kubernates cluster, most of their endpoints can only be accessed with the accessed token (legacy filter can't be removed). However, I would like one service to call the other without a token for a particular endpoint (let's say service A call service B). Is it possible to specify the service name rather than the ip to be whitelisted in service B? I don't want to make the endpoint to be publicly accessible. Do I have to convert to IP like this

`InetAddress ipaddress = InetAddress.getByName(service);`

Is there something smart for Kubernetes services?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use the internal kubernetes dns [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) so you don't have to specify the ip address.